# How to generate an asynchronous reset verilog always blocks with chisel

Tags: verilog, fpga, chisel

Chisel generate always blocks with only clock in sensivity list :

```
always @posedge(clk) begin
  [...]
end
```

Is it possible to configure Module to use an asynchronous reset and generate an always block like this ?

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
   [...]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Chisel 3.2.0, there is support for synchronous, asynchronous, and abstract reset types. Based on the type of reset explicitly specified or inferred, you will get canonical synchronous or asynchronous Verilog output.

To try to show this more fully, consider the following `MultiIOModule` which has three resets:

- The implicit `reset` input which has an abstract reset type (this is "abstract reset")
- The explicit `syncReset` input which has a `Bool` type (this is "synchronous reset")
- The explicit `asyncReset` input which has an `AsyncReset` type (this is "asynchronous reset")

Using `withReset`, specific reset connections can then be used for different registers in the design:

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.stage.ChiselStage

class Foo extends MultiIOModule {
  val syncReset  = IO(Input(Bool()      ))
  val asyncReset = IO(Input(AsyncReset()))

  val in          = IO(Input( Bool()))
  val outAbstract = IO(Output(Bool()))
  val outSync     = IO(Output(Bool()))
  val outAsync    = IO(Output(Bool()))

  val regAbstract =                         RegNext(in, init=0.U)
  val regSync     = withReset(syncReset)  { RegNext(in, init=0.U) }
  val regAsync    = withReset(asyncReset) { RegNext(in, init=0.U) }

  outAbstract := regAbstract
  outSync     := regSync
  outAsync    := regAsync
}
```

This then produces the following Verilog when compiled with: `(new ChiselStage).emitVerilog(new Foo)`:

```
module Foo(
  input   clock,
  input   reset,
  input   syncReset,
  input   asyncReset,
  input   in,
  output  outAbstract,
  output  outSync,
  output  outAsync
);
  reg  regAbstract;
  reg  regSync;
  reg  regAsync;
  assign outAbstract = regAbstract;
  assign outSync = regSync;
  assign outAsync = regAsync;
  always @(posedge clock) begin
    if (reset) begin
      regAbstract <= 1'h0;
    end else begin
      regAbstract <= in;
    end
    if (syncReset) begin
      regSync <= 1'h0;
    end else begin
      regSync <= in;
    end
  end
  always @(posedge clock or posedge asyncReset) begin
    if (asyncReset) begin
      regAsync <= 1'h0;
    end else begin
      regAsync <= in;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Note: that in Chisel 3.2 the top-level abstract reset would always be set to synchronous reset. In Chisel 3.3.0, two traits were added: `RequireSyncReset` and `RequireAsyncReset`. These can be used to change the reset type of the register connected to `regAbstract` from synchronous to asynchronous. Recompiling the design with `(new ChiselStage).emitVerilog(new Foo with RequireAsyncReset)`, changes the `regAbstract` logic to

```
always @(posedge clock or posedge reset) begin
  if (reset) begin
    regAbstract <= 1'h0;
  end else begin
    regAbstract <= in;
  end
end
```

For more information, the [Chisel website has more information on resets](https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/reset.html).

Comment: Hi, will `with RequireAsyncReset` affect the sub-modules recursively?

Comment: Mixing that in will likely have that effect. The abstract reset in the top is being forced to `AsyncReset`. Submodules that connect to this reset line will then be converted to `AsyncReset` (or result in a failure if you connect `AsyncReset` to `Bool`).

Comment: seems only the default `reset` is affected by the trait. Resets that were declared as `Reset()` explicitly in top level module is not affected by the `RequireAsyncReset` trait, and triggers a firrtl error `Abstract Reset not allowed as top-level input: io.rst`. Any workaround?

Comment: Either make those top-level resets the type of reset they should be (`Bool` or `AsynReset`) or, if you do want abstract reset in the top level and are trying to generate different versions, then use a `RawModule` wrapper with the concrete reset types and do the connections to your abstract resets. Would that work for your situation?

Answer (score 4):

Chisel versions prior to 3.2.0 do not have support for asynchronous resets.

It looks like the way to do this in Chisel is to use synchronous resets:

```
always @posedge(clk) begin
  if (reset) begin
  [...]
  end 
  else 
  [...]
  end
end
```

For more discussion on the topic:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chisel-users/4cc4SyB5mk8