# How to code a asynchronous reset in chisel

Tags: chisel

How to add the reset signal to the sensitivity list in the generated Verilog code when writing a Chisel code, for example the code below for D flip flop:

```
val x = Reg(init = UInt(0, width = 1))
    x := io.D
    io.Q := x
```

will generate a Verilog code as this:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(reset) begin
      x <= 1'h0;
    end else begin
      x <= io_D;
    end
end
```

as seen the reset is synchronous with the clock, how to code Chisel to generate something like this:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
    if(reset) begin
      x <= 1'h0;
    end else begin
      x <= io_D;
    end
end
```

where the reset signal is in the sensitivity list and hence asynchronous.

**Edit:**
As pointed by chrisvp there is another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767059/how-to-generate-an-asynchronous-reset-verilog-always-blocks-with-chisel) and a discussion in chisel-users google group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chisel-users/4cc4SyB5mk8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate an asynchronous reset verilog always blocks with chisel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767059/how-to-generate-an-asynchronous-reset-verilog-always-blocks-with-chisel)

Comment: Yes, chrisvp has mentioned that see my edit.

Comment: That's an automatic comment in response to a close vote.

Comment: oh silly me haha @user1155120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a copy of [How to generate an asynchronous reset verilog always blocks with chisel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29767059/how-to-generate-an-asynchronous-reset-verilog-always-blocks-with-chisel)

If really required, you could consider forcing this by considering the rst as a second clock domain as described in the [Chisel manual](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/2.2.0/chisel-manual.pdf) , though I wouldn't recommend to do so.

Comment: I didn't see that question. why you don't recommend that?

Comment: Go with the flow. Unless you really need an asynchronous reset, live with what Chisel provides and don't try to hack/bend it ... Plus, I don't think enforcing an asynchronous reset by adding a second clock domain will be trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Since Chisel 3.2.0, asynchronous reset is supported. The example code can be implemented with the following:

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.stage.ChiselStage

class Foo extends RawModule {
  val clk   = IO(Input(Clock()))
  val reset = IO(Input(AsyncReset()))
  val io    = IO(Input(new Bundle{ val D = UInt(1.W) }))
  val out   = IO(Output(Bool()))

  val x = withClockAndReset(clk, reset) { RegNext(io.D, init=0.U) }
  out := x
}
```

This will then produce the following Verilog logic for register `x`:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
  if (reset) begin
    x <= 1'h0;
  end else begin
    x <= io_D;
  end
end
```

To use synchronous reset, change the type of `reset` from `AsyncReset` to `Bool`.